# Based on these DBCC SHOWCONTIG stats, should I index this table?

Tags: sql-server, index

I have a SQL 2008 Standard server on full mirror (safety). I reorganize all indexes weekly. I am looking into rebuilding a few indexes to improve performance. I ran DBCC SHOWCONTIG on my largest, most accessed table and got the following results.

```
DBCC SHOWCONTIG scanning 'MYTABLE' table...
Table: 'MYTABLE' (12345678); index ID: 1, database ID: 7
TABLE level scan performed.
- Pages Scanned................................: 738663
- Extents Scanned..............................: 92661
- Extent Switches..............................: 92720
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 8.0
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 99.58% [92333:92721]
- Logical Scan Fragmentation ..................: 0.35%
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 41.58%
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 467.9
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 94.22%
```

Would rebuilding the index make sense on this table? Would there be any benefits to doing so?

Comment: Please switch to using [`sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) -- `DBCC SHOWCONTIG` has been deprecated for quite some time now.

Comment: http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html -- Ola Hallegren has the best script to do the job for you. I second on Jon's comment!

Comment: Denis- Ill take a look.